# How to change color?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color, itemize

How to change the colour of the ball in which the item numbers are written?.
Help me please.

[image]

Comment: Help out the community by posted a minimal document that replicates your current state... Pretty please?

Comment: Sorry. That's not how this site works. Please provide the code which you use to produce the image and somebody will show you how to change the colour. Why should we start from scratch when you already have the code for the image? (And if you didn't, you could still provide something.) See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5):

Those colours are taken from `item projected` so use

```
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white,bg=red}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white,bg=red}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LuisRivera And next time please provide a MWE :-)

Answer (score 2):

The origin of this code is different, but - maybe - can help you:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\gooditem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=green}\item #1} 
\newcommand{\pooritem}[1]{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red}\item #1} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \gooditem good
    \pooritem bad
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Very nice... but not practical for color blind.

Comment: I know. But we can use a brown instead red. There are tables that explain how use the color with the four types of color blind if the colour have a meaning.

Comment: Look here: http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-vision/what-is-color-blindness. I do not remember the exact source (maybe the recommendations about HTML style and color.